# How to move logs from DB to files in Magento EE?

Tags: database, magento, logging

I need to change log saving place from DB to files. I found only one way - rewrite Mage_Log module resource models and modify save() function for every resource model, but, as I understand right, it's not very good way. Please, tell me, how can I save logs into files, but not into DB (eg: visitor logs)?

Comment: I don't have any use for those logs so I turn them off.

Comment: But I need to change log place, because we use them.

Comment: If you insist.  I posted an answer with some directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to override app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Vistor.php.

In there, you'll find several places where it's writing this information into the DB which makes your site that much slower.

To answer your question, you'll need to change the following method(s):

```
_saveUrlInfo($visitor)
_saveVisitorUrl($visitor)
_saveCustomerInfo($visitor)
_saveQuoteInfo($visitor)
```

For those of you who may have landed on this page looking for information on how to disable the logs all together, you can find instructions here:
http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/12/how-to-disable-magento-logging-to-the-database/